# No [ManagedType] was found for the key class

Tags: spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA, H2, EclipseLink, Java Config (no xml). My problem is that I am getting this *No [ManagedType] was found for the key class* error below. It suggests adding `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` to my `persistence.xml`, but I am not using xml for configuration, so I am not sure how to fix it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.foo.data.repository.RepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.foo.data.repository.UserRepository com.foo.data.repository.RepositoryTest.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.foo.data.model.User] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.foo.data.model.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
   at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
   at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
   at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is an excerpt from my `@Configuration` class.

```
@ComponentScan(
      basePackages = { "com.foo.*"},
      excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,
      value = Configuration.class))
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.foo.data.repository")
public class SeleniumAppTestConfig implements InitializingBean {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
      return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("SeleniumCreateScript.sql").build();
   }

   @Bean
   public Properties jpaProperties() {
       Properties props = new Properties();
       props.setProperty("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-tables");
       props.setProperty("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
       props.setProperty("eclipselink.logging.level", "FINEST");
       props.setProperty("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
       return props;
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      final PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new PersistenceProvider();

      final EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter =
            new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
      vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
      vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
      emf.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.data.model");
      emf.setLoadTimeWeaver(new SimpleLoadTimeWeaver());
      emf.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider);
      emf.setPersistenceUnitName("SeleniumTests");
      emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
      emf.afterPropertiesSet();
      return emf;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            entityManagerFactory().getObject() );

      return transactionManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public EclipseLinkJpaDialect exceptionTranslator() {
      return new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
   }

}
```

Here is my Entity class (in the `com.foo.data.model package`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "SELENIUM")
public class User {
   @Id
   @Column (name = "USERNAME")
   private String username;
   @Column (name = "PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   public String getUsername() {
      return username;
   }
   public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
   }
   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return String.format(
            "User[username=%s, password='%s']",
            username, password);
   }

}
```

Here is my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository <User, String> {
   List<User> findByLastUsername(String username);
}
```

And finally, here is my Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SeleniumAppTestConfig.class)
public class RepositoryTest {

   /** Logger for this class. */
   private static final Logger LOG =
         Logger.getLogger(RepositoryTest.class);

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Test
   public void testThings() {
      final Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
      for (User user: users) {
         LOG.info("user [" + user + "].");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Solved my problem by moving to Hibernate instead of EclipseLink.

Comment: This was my solution too. I had multiple datasource and used autoconfiguration. The sad thing is the error refered to persistence.xml but I did not even had such a file.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the entities base package using `@EntityScan` on your `SeleniumAppTestConfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Just give a dummy name to each of the individual PersistenceUnitName. 
No persistence.xml needed

factory.setPersistenceUnitName("dummy1");
factory.setPersistenceUnitName("dummy2");

Comment: This did the trick finally. After getting it to work with hibernate I tried this with eclipselink and if worked. so im sticking with EL for now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is a mix of configuration via `persistence.xml` and component scanning. The setup defines a persistence unit name (in the setup of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`) which makes Spring use that and drop the packages to scan as it can't augment an existing persistence unit.

This would've been revealed by activating debug logging as `DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.readPersistenceUnitInfos(…)` [logs a message](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/ca75c2843a40028c37f8665a4049e5442a725c58/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java#L515-L520) in exactly that case.

I've filed [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23257) to improve the logging in that erroneous configuration state to make the problem more obvious.

Comment: I don't see him using xml for configuration. He also says so in his post

Answer (score 2):

Update to eclipse link 2.7.8-RC1

Comment: I used the version 2.7.1 and had the same issue. I confirm that after updating to 2.7.8 the issue is gone! Incredible!!!! Thanks